# Magento 2.4 in cPanel error 404

Tags: 404, cpanel

Unfortunately I have to ask because I can't solve the 404 error. Previously I had the internal server error but I solved it. Now it's like if I didn't have index.php? because I cannot find the error, it is not possible to access the administrator panel and the main url does not show the example only these words

```
Index of / https://slakterbutikk.no/
    Name    Last modified   Size    Description
    CHANGELOG.md
    COPYING.txt
    Gruntfile.js.sample
    LICENSE.txt
    LICENSE_AFL.txt
    SECURITY.md
    auth.json.sample
    composer.json
    composer.lock 
    error_log
    grunt-config.json.sa..>
    nginx.conf.sample
    package.json.sample
    setup/
```

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Thanks for your time
regards
Nico

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there might be an issue with your Magento installation or configuration. Here are some steps you can try to resolve the issue:

1. Check if the index.php file exists in the Magento root directory. If it doesn't exist, copy it from a fresh Magento installation or download it from the Magento GitHub repository.
2. Check your server logs to see if there are any errors that can give you a clue about the root cause of the problem. The error_log file you see in the index page is a good starting point. You may also want to check the Apache or Nginx error logs.
3. Make sure the web server is configured to use the correct document root directory and that it has read and execute permissions on the Magento files and directories.
4. Check the Magento configuration file (app/etc/env.php) to ensure that the database credentials are correct and that the base URL is set correctly.
5. Clear the Magento cache by deleting the contents of the var/cache directory.
6. Check if the URL rewrite module is enabled on the web server. If it is not enabled, you may need to enable it or configure Magento to use the standard index.php URL format.
7. If none of the above steps work, try a fresh installation of Magento and see if you encounter the same issue. If you do, then it may be a server configuration issue, in which case you may need to consult with your hosting provider or server administrator.

I hope these suggestions help you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hei thanks for your reply

another official website where I can download magento?
I think github dosent work. I have that problem around weeks

This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

Answer (score 0):

Now magento does not provide the URL to download. Now magento has changed their policy. You can only download and setup magento using composer only...
please upvote if suggestion you like do not say thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I strayed too much from the subject, but I have searched for more information and I see that I am really very tied when it comes to working with him. In Cpanel I don't have access to whm so I can't update mysql and I see that every automatic installation I do on magento is a new problem using versions 2.4 for example. It discourages me from using this platform because I don't see simple solutions. Github doesn't work for me either so I can't download from an official page doing everything legally. I don't know whether to install magento and report all the errors here and see if we can solve it together but I think it will be many hours without knowing its end.